# Returning back to login page

Tags: php, codeigniter

After login i am redirecting user to forum controller, but somehow it execute constrctor but do not enter into `index()` function. when i try to exit("line 7") its stop execution, but when i try to exit in index it wont

```
<?php
class Forum extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('ForumModel');   
            //exit("line 7");
    }
    function index()
    {
        exit("line9");
        //print_r($this->session->userdata);
```

Any help appreciated!!

Comment: It should work when you redirect it with, http://localhost/ci/index.php/forum.. Post your redirection code

Comment: @EdwinAlex: i am redirecting it "redirect('forum')"

Comment: Have u added routing paths correctly

Comment: @Arunu: yes i set is correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling a complete week i got the answer-

Session values are getting destroy by codeigniter.

By default CodeIgniter stores the session data in a cookie, which has an upper limit of 2KB-4KB in size depending on browser.
If you are trying to store more than 4KB of data in the session you will start running into issues.

So i opted to store session values in DB.

For more details: http://goo.gl/YPllj0

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter always execute the index function if you hit the controller with that url that have not any function name.So please check URL where you are redirecting and if all is good then test that is really index function called by commenting your all other code lines.

Comment: try redirect('/forum/'); ... make sure you are using correct relative URL

Answer (score 0):

You are being redirect in `ForumModel`, or try `parent::__construct(TRUE);` your session is not generating or might not working properly. I hope this helps.
If you have session problem than see what is session is printing.

```
print_r($this->session->userdata);
```

this will print all session data

Comment: you are right my session is getting destroy automatically. ?And this is not working parent::__construct(TRUE); Thax for your time

Answer (score 0):

Here Your Model is not letting the control jump to the index() method. Please check your model (its constructor and all other functions in stack, when Forum class is called ). there  might be some commmand which is not getting fulfilled and allowing the execution to proceed. Please check the model and the Resources associated with it. Thanks